# Let $B=\{(a,b]:a,b\in R,a<b\}$ is basis of topology $T$ on $R$ show that each interval$(a,b)$ in open in $(R,T)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

please check my proof

Suppose $B$ is basis of topology on $R$

Let $U$ is collection of union of all interval $(a_{n},b_{n})$

There exist some interval $\{I:(a_{n},b_{n}):a,b\in R\}$

for some interval
$(a_{n},b_{n})$

such that

$(a_{n},b_{n})\in I\subseteq  U$

therefore U is open and each interval (a,b) is open

Comment: I don't follow your proof. If you want to show $(a, b)$ is open, I suggest finding a family of basis elements $(x_i, y_i]$, indexed by some index set $I$, such that $(a, b) = \bigcup_{i \in I} (x_i, y_i]$. Hint: make $y_i$ increasing and convergent.

Comment: You didn't proved anything.  Let $N$ s.t. $a<b-\frac{1}{N}$. Then $$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n\geq N}\left(a,b-\frac{1}{n}\right].$$

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with a collection of intervals $(a_n, b_n)$. You're only supposed to take a single (arbitrary) interval $(a, b)$. Then use the basis elements you've been given (_those_ you can use a collection of).

Comment: thank for comment. It's hard to understand topology by self-study -  -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That it is a base for a topology I just showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2948122/4280).

Every set $(a,b)$ is open, because if $x \in (a,b)$, then $x \in [x,b) \subseteq (a,b)$ and $[x,b) \in \mathcal{B}$, so $(a,b)$ is open in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$.