# Show that $B=\{[a, b)\subset R \mid a<b\}$ is basis of topology on $R$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Please check my proof

let

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}[a_{i},b_{i})$

such that
$a\leq U\leqslant b$

We must prove for each $x\in U$ there is open set V in B such that

$x\in V\subset U$

let $x\in U$ and we define

$V=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} (a_{j},b_{j})$ $ a\leq a_{j}\leq b_{j}\leq b$

since we define $V$ as collection of open interval then it's open set

then for each $x\in U$ there exist s some open subset in $V$ such that $x\in V$

since we define $V=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} (a_{j},b_{j})$ $ a\leq a_{j}\leq b_{j}\leq b$

the $x\in V\subseteq U$

then $B=\{[a, b)\subset R \mid a<b\} $ is basis of topology on $R$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check the two conditions:

a. $\bigcup \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{R}$: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x \in [x,x+1)$ and $[x,x+1) \in \mathcal{B}$, so we're done.

b. For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$: let $B_1 = [a,b)$ and $B_2 = [c,d)$. If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, this means that $a \le x < b$ and $c \le x < d$ which is equivalent to $\max(a,c) \le x < \min(b,d)$. So we can take $B_3 = [\max(a,c), \min(b,d)) \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ and we're done.

Your proof makes no sense at all.

Comment: is it definition for basis ? is it different from proof the set is basis that generate topology ?

Comment: thank for answer I think if I follow the theorem that show the basis generate topology it is the same as to prove it is basis

Comment: @monkeylover401 You just have to check the two conditions and the theorem assures us that the set of unions form the base form a topology. You don't have to reprove the theorem every time. That's the point of theorems. And the second condition is very clearly what we need to show the generated candidate topology to be closed under (finite) intersections.

Comment: thank you for answer  ^ ^

Comment: To show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for an already given topology $\mathcal{T}$ we need to show that all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ are in $\mathcal{T}$, and also that for all $O \in \mathcal{T}$, and all $x \in O$ we have some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subseteq O$. A different statement altogether. @monkeylover401